# Writing $3\sin(x)+4\cos(x)$ in the form of $r \sin(x-a)$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to write $3\sin(x) + 4\cos(x)$ in the form of $r\sin(x-a)$.

Expanding $r\sin(x-a): r\sin(x)\cos(a)-r\sin(a)\cos(x)$

Comparing the two forms (The original equation and the expanded form): $3=r\cos(a)$ and $4=-r\sin(a)$.

Getting $r$:

$$\begin{align*}
3^2 + 4^2 &= r^2 \cos(a)^2 + r^2 \sin(a)^2\\
25 &= r^2 (\cos(a)^2 + \sin(a)^2)\\
25 &= r^2\\
r &= -5, 5
\end{align*}$$

Getting $a$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{-r\sin(a)}{ r\cos(a)} &= \frac{3}{4}\\
\tan(a) &= -\frac{3}{4}\\
a &= \arctan(-3/4)\\
a &= -36.87, 143.13\\
\end{align*}$$

The questions:-
There are two values for both $r$ and $a$, how should I choose the values to be in the final form?

Comment: What do you mean in the final form? (Btw, +1 for showing your working)

Comment: (a) After you get your solution, graph it (and the original function) and see if they agree.  (b) Why do you think the problem (or any problem) has only one solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two values of $a$ differ by $180^{\circ}$. Since $\sin(y\pm 180^{\circ}) = -\sin(y)$, you want to pick $r$ and $a$ in such a way that $r\sin(x-a)$ has the same sign as $3\sin x+ 4\cos x$.

When $x=0$, $3\sin x + 4\cos x=4$ is positive; so you want to pick $r$ and $a$ so that $r\sin(-a)$ is positive. This happens when $r=5$ and $a=-36.87^{\circ}$; or when $r=-5$ and $a=143.13$. The two choices work, the other two possibilities do not.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= 3 \sin(x) + 4 \cos(x) \\
f(x) &= 5\left(\frac{3}{5} \sin(x) + \frac{4}{5} \cos(x) \right)
\end{align*}$$

Let $\sin(y) = 4/5$ and $\cos(y) =3/5$, for some real number $y$.
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= 5\left(\cos(y)\sin(x) + \sin(y)\cos(x)\right)\\
f(x) &= 5\sin(x+y)&\text{(where }y = \arcsin(4/5)\text{)}
\end{align*}$$
Using trigonometric tables, $y = 36.87$.
$$f(x) = 5\sin(x + 36.87^{\circ})$$ 
which can also be written as
$$f(x) = 5 \sin (180 - x - 36.87) = -5\sin(x - 144.13).$$
This justifies the 2 values of $a$ and $r$ in $r\sin(x−a)$.